# Is the ecu module is causing a short?

Tags: wiring, renault, short, bcm

**S**o this problem I'm having is regarding a very annoying Renault van and it's liking to blowing a fuse.

The fuse in question is shared between  a relay, two different modules and the heating controls.

The suspect module is called a BCM body control module or UCH as the french like to call it.  This occured after driving over a small bump in the road, I lost power steering and a whole load of warning lights appeared on the dash, stop, brake fault, esc, abs.

This BCM controls a whole load of different systems mostly things like electric windows, central Locking, interior lights, the ignition key to start etc.

When it blows the fuse it seems that only half of the module stops working as the Van can still be started and the electric windows still work. I got some rather dubious wiring diagrams and found that there are two separate feeds of power from different fuses going to two of the four plugs on the BCM.

Now they way this is designed is that all four plugs have to be plugged in of the whole thing doesn't work, even though there are two separate section active, they must have inputs and outputs randomly distributed throughout the four plugs, *I'm sure 'sadist' is a french word, marquee de sarde.*

Now here's the kicker, the power steering isn't even controlled by this module, this module links to another module which then sends a signal to the power steering pump to switch on and returns a signal through the engine management module then back to the second module. *If picasso designed a wiring system this is it, except he was spanish not french.*

So the question is is the fuse being blown by a short in the BCM or in one of the subsystems that the BCM is controlling? The BCM has a couple of small relays inside, it can't be swapped out for just any other, it has to be the same part number and needs to be cloned by soldering wires to smd points and via on the board then EPROM data extracted then flashed onto a donor unit, this process costs a few hundred pounds compared to the couple of thousand Renault charge for a new unit and coded to the vehicle.

Oh did I mention that this fault intermittent, sometimes when you replace the fuse it doesn't blow and other times it goes into hard short, popping the fuse fast.
I've had the dash completely torn down to get at the loom and most of the subsystem switches and sensors, when the fuse doesn't blow I've wiggled cables unplugged and replugged various things in an attempt to recreate the fault and blow the fuse but to no avail, you then drive it a short way and it blows the fuse.

I've had someone plug in a very good diagnostic machine, got a whole load of codes, most of which are the result of the fuse being blown and half the BCM not working, but these codes have not really led to any solutions.

I have now found the only module in the UK with the same part numbers and am going to send it away to be cloned, if this doesn't solve the problem I'm not sure where that leaves me, I'll have a £21000 paperweight or shed.

Any ideas anyone?

*I think Renault just design their stuff to fail to keep selling parts and services, engines are great chassis is great but the electrics and gearboxes are designed and built by monkeys, on the plastic case for the BCM it states the if dropped do not use and recycle and this is in a commercial van that drives on British roads with potholes all over the place*

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!